# url rewrite not working on multiple and dynamic values

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contactus\/?/?$ index.php?goto=contactus
RewriteRule ^home\/?/?$ index.php?goto=home
RewriteRule ^event\/?/?$ index.php?goto=event
RewriteRule ^album\/?/?([a-z0-9-]+)\/?/?$ index.php?goto=home&albumid=$1
```

The problem is on last RewriteRule, first three are working as they are supposed to. Problem is in last one, when i open URL like `http://localhost/album/56c9eb6b1fe75`,it doesn't work properly. But when i try this: `http://localhost/index.php?goto=home&albumid=123`then this works good

PS:

By `doesn't work properly` I mean: [image: This is how it opens], and[image: this is how it is supposed to open].
Check the address bars in both images to understand the problem. In first one i think the bootstrap and other css files are not loaded.

Comment: What does `doesn't work properly` mean? You get an error, goes to wrong page, etc.? Why do you have `\/?/?` you want 2 `/`s to be optional? The `/` doesnt need to be escaped, it isn't a delimiter here.

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: Isn't that just because you have relative path to css, js, and/or other resources?

Comment: if `http://localhost/album/56c9eb6b1fe75` didn't work, but `http://localhost/index.php?goto=home&albumid=123` did... why didn't you try `http://localhost/album/123`?

Comment: Side note, with routing, you want to make sure the links to local css/js/images start with `/` instead of relying on relative for the browser, as it will try and pull it from relative to `/album/css`, etc...

Comment: @Jon `http://localhost/album/123` also don't work and `http://localhost/index.php?goto=home&albumid=56c9eb6b1fe75` always works, thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your update I believe the issue is that you are using relative paths on your page. This makes your CSS, JS, and all other resources (images) load from the current path `/album/`. You should add a leading `/` to your paths so they load from the root of your server.

A call to the stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

will load as

```
example.com/admin/style.css
```

if you make it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

it knows to go to the root of your domain.

```
example.com/style.css
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Depending on the PHP code behind it, I would think images in a gallery would be absolute... But this is definitely an issue that OP will have to overcome. +1

Comment: Thanks, that was the actual problem which i couldn't find in hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^album/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?goto=home&albumid=$1
```

Comment: Ah, the update indicates that actually you have a completely different problem than what you ask: it is not that the rewriting does not work, but that your paths to css styles are wrong. You will have to post your code!